# Android - Using different resource files for a base activity?

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android so go easy on me!
I'm building an app that catalogs a bunch of restaurants and displays each of their menus, depending on the selection of the user.

Is it possible to store the info of each restaurant in a separate resource file, and have a template-like activity that will display the particular info that the user selects from a spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can replace views (which can be loaded from different layout.xml files). You can load a layout XML file using LayoutInflater. You can add views into a layout (which is a ViewGroup) using one of the addView() methods, and there are also methods to remove views.

It is unusual, however, to hardcode data into any layout. It is usually better to store the data in a database or file, and use a layout which is more like a template, where you replace the data in the layout at runtime.

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing! Seems a lot cleaner, thanks!